# flask request.get_json cannot deserialize nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests

My data to send over requests is a nested dictionary so I have to manually serialize it.

```
req = {
    "data": {
      "field1": 420000,
      "field2": 3,
      "field3": 6840
    },
    "weights": {
      "weight1": 1,
      "weight2": 1,
      "weight3": 1
    },
    "num_trials": 15
}
```

On the client side I have used the following to send request

```
def to_serialize_nestd_dict(val):
    if hasattr(val, '__dict__'):
        return val.__dict__

    return val

@lambdawarmer.warmer(send_metric=False)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    json_str = json.dumps(event, default=to_serialize_nestd_dict)
    res = requests.post(url=f'http://{SERVER_IP}:5084/predict',
                        data=json_str,
                        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
                       )
```

On the server side I have used the following to parse request

```
from flask import request
client_req = request.get_json(silent=False)
```

However I always get the following parsing error

```
Key Error: 'data'
```

when I tried to retrieve the "data" field of client_req.

It seems like flask's get_json cannot deserialize nested dictionaries. Could somebody confirm that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the content of your data in the headers of the request as such:

```py
requests.post(
   url=f'http://{SERVER_IP}:5084/predict',
   headers={
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
   data=json.dumps(req, default=to_serialize_nestd_dict)
)
```

Concerning the server side. You must not use `json.loads(request.get_json(silent=False))` but just `request.get_json(silent=False)`. Actuallly, `request.get_json` already deserialize the json content and returns it as a python dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But after adopting your solution, I got a different error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: I updated the answer concerning the server side issue.

Comment: Thanks! I follow your instruction to get rid of json.loads(). But now the error is changed to "KeyError: 'data'". Apparently flask's get_json can't automatically deserialize nested dictionaries.

Comment: Can you provide the deserialized data, right after the request.get_json ? get_json simply apply the json.loads method [source_code](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/_modules/flask/wrappers.html#Request.get_json)

Comment: Sorry but that flask server is running in a AWS ECR. So I don't know how to print it out. Do you know of a way of printing out from AWS ECS?

Comment: If somewhere you can see logs from flask, you can try to use the flask app logger with `app.logger.info("")`. Can you provide the full stacktrace of the KeyError ? Is it possible that you call "data" key somewhere after deserialisation ?

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately I have no luck with that. On the other hand, I use the same code and run the flask server locally in an EC2 instance. Everything works well. Hence it seems not the problem with my code. I don't know what happened to AWS lambda.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253394/discussion-between-ftorre-and-physicsmath).